# Unable to retrieve data con pydelicious cuando inicializo un diccionario

Tags: python, python-2.7, api

Quiero utilizar funciones para crear una base de datos entre usuarios y items. Utilizo las funciones que pueden ver aquí que permiten hacerlo sobre el API del.icio.us.

Sin embargo cuando inicializo el diccionario de usuarios hay problemas :

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from deliciousrec import *
>>> delusers = initializeUserDict('programming')
<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>, 4 tries left.
<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>, 3 tries left.
<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>, 2 tries left.
<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>, 1 tries left.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "deliciousrec.py", line 10, in initializeUserDict
    for p1 in get_popular(tag=tag)[0:count]:
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydelicious/__init__.py", line 1044, in get_popular
    return getrss(tag=tag, popular=1)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydelicious/__init__.py", line 1028, in getrss
    return dlcs_rss_request(tag=tag, popular=popular, user=user, url=url)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydelicious/__init__.py", line 457, in dlcs_rss_request
    rss = http_request(url).read()
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydelicious/__init__.py", line 241, in http_request
    "Unable to retrieve data at '%s', %s" % (url, e)
pydelicious.PyDeliciousException: Unable to retrieve data at 'http://feeds.delicious.com/rss/popular/programming', <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

A mi parecer puede ser a causa de `get_popular` o `get_urlposts`. Pero ya habia errores cuando intenté descargar el API :

```
(test4) mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/collective$ easy_install DeliciousAPI
Searching for DeliciousAPI
Best match: DeliciousAPI 1.6.7
Processing DeliciousAPI-1.6.7-py3.6.egg
DeliciousAPI 1.6.7 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/DeliciousAPI-1.6.7-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for DeliciousAPI
Searching for BeautifulSoup>=3.0.7
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/BeautifulSoup/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/ee/295988deca1a5a7accd783d0dfe14524867e31abb05b6c0eeceee49c759d/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=6a8cb4401111e011b579c8c52a51cdab970041cc543814bbd9577a4529fe1cdb
Best match: BeautifulSoup 3.2.1
Processing BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-owwa0x3c/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1/setup.cfg
Running BeautifulSoup-3.2.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-owwa0x3c/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1/egg-dist-tmp-2c8ro1a_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 44, in _execfile
    code = compile(script, filename, 'exec')
  File "/tmp/easy_install-owwa0x3c/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1/setup.py", line 22
    print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2315, in main
    **kw
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 140, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/mike/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/mike/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/mike/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 415, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 676, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 707, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dists[0], deps, "Using")
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 749, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1060, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1072, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 676, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 702, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 887, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1155, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1141, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/home/mike/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/home/mike/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/programming/collective/test4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 44, in _execfile
    code = compile(script, filename, 'exec')
  File "/tmp/easy_install-owwa0x3c/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1/setup.py", line 22
    print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```